# How .NET Remoting handles changes of IP address in Remoting Server side

Tags: .net, remoting

Precondition - the remoting server and client are both setup, the client is able to invoke methods and receive events in/from the server side by client-activated business object.

Change the ip address of remoting server with keeping the server and client running, the client is still able to do the above tasks.

This is tricky.

EDIT:
bindTo was removed when setting the channels

Comment: Are you aware that Remoting has been deprecated in favor of WCF?

Comment: It has better performance than WCF. Actually many applicationss still use it.

Comment: See my post below. There are only two general scenarios where .NET Remoting is faster than WCF: when remoting data across appdomains in the same process, and when remoting ADO.NET dataset objects.

Comment: Change it to WCF. You'll benefit a lot from it.

Answer (score 0):

C'mon, it's 2010... make it a WCF app already.

And to answer your "performance" concern check out the thread [Performance WCF vs .NET remoting](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/5736b856-bd90-4fd1-968f-5aea90f42fbb/)

Full comparison between WCF and other previous communication technologies [HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb310550.aspx)

You are going to save yourself from some headaches and hear-pulling scenarios by going WCF. It's a safe bet and let me assure you, you'll not regret it.

Quoting Saurabh Gupta (WCF PM at MS):

> When migrating distributed applications written with ASP.NET Web Services, WSE, .NET Enterprise Services and .NET Remoting to WCF, the performance is at least comparable to the other existing Microsoft distributed communication technologies. In most cases, the performance is significantly better for WCF over the other existing technologies. Another important characteristic of WCF is that the throughput performance is inherently scalable from a uni processor to quad processor.
>
> To summarize the results, WCF is 25%—50% faster than ASP.NET Web Services, and approximately 25% faster than .NET Remoting. Comparison with .NET Enterprise Service is load dependant, as in one case WCF is nearly 100% faster but in another scenario it is nearly 25% slower. For WSE 2.0/3.0 implementations, migrating them to WCF will obviously provide the most significant performance gains of almost 4x.

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Answer (score 0):

The only scenarios where .NET Remoting is faster than WCF are when remoting data between appdomains in the same process and when serializing ADO.NET DataSet objects.

Other than that, WCF is almost always faster: [A Performance Comparison of Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) with Existing Distributed Communication Technologies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb310550.aspx):

Further, when hosted within IIS, WCF services are automatically mapped to a network connection's new IP address. The same cannot be said for .NET Remoting.

While some existing apps continue to use .NET Remoting, it is deprecated and you should realize that any .NET code you write and deploy will at some point need to be replaced. Better to do the port to WCF now rather than later when you're up against a brick-wall-deadline.

Comment: How is that different from what I said before. Do you think you are bringing something new to answer the question?

Comment: Also, is there any more relevance to the question than the previous answer?

Comment: @M.Stramm: Since all the comments and replies offer perf-related answers, I believe the OP (for some reason) subsequently edited this question, changing its title and content.

Comment: @RichardTurner: nope, nothing in the edit history. only the "Edit: ..." part was added